# How do I scale down 360 image using aframe?

Tags: aframe

So this code is directly from aframe 360 image source code. When I run this code, it is in full screen. I was wondering if there is a way to scale this image down, so that I can fit multiple images on a webpage. Thank you!

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>360&deg; Image</title>
<meta name="description" content="360&deg; Image - A-Frame">
<script src="assets/js/aframe-master.js"></script>
```

```
<a-scene>
  <a-sky src="assets/images/123.jpg" rotation="0 -130 0"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have more than one sky object visible at the same time. It is not entirely clear from your question what you really want. Multiple  rectangular images floating around you? Check out the ideaspace vr blog
https://www.ideaspacevr.org/theme-preview/ideaspace-compass-blog

https://www.ideaspacevr.org/